# sort and ls -- why aren't capitalized letters sorted first?

Tags: ls, sort, locale

I want a sorting like this, with capitalized letters before lowercase:

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 0 0    183 2014-10-14 20:17 ./CHECKSUMS.md5
-rw-r--r--.  1 0 0    185 2014-10-14 20:17 ./CHECKSUMS.asc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:01 ./a
-rw-------.  1 0 0 464140 2013-12-16 19:11 ./a/pam-1.1.8-x86_64-2mg.txz
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 19:55 ./b
-rw-------.  1 0 0 464140 2014-10-14 19:55 ./b/pam-1.1.8-x86_64-2mg.txz
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./c
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./e
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./f
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./g
```

I use this command:

```
find -L . -print  | sort -d | xargs ls -nld --time-style=long-iso
```

and result is:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 29 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 20:17 .
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:01 ./a
-rw-------.  1 0 0 464140 2013-12-16 19:11 ./a/pam-1.1.8-x86_64-2mg.txz
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 19:55 ./b
-rw-------.  1 0 0 464140 2014-10-14 19:55 ./b/pam-1.1.8-x86_64-2mg.txz
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./c
-rw-r--r--.  1 0 0    183 2014-10-14 20:17 ./CHECKSUMS.md5
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./e
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./f
drwxr-xr-x.  2 0 0   4096 2014-10-14 18:00 ./g
```

How can I get the sort order I want?

Comment: solution found,must use -t "." on sort and sort column after .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simply use export LC_ALL=C,make the script with ls,sort,etc
and then return to you favourite LC,in my case UTF8.

Comment: Instead of `export LC_ALL`, it is probably preferable to set collation order only for that particular `ls` command thus: `LC_COLLATE=C ls -nl --time-style=long-iso`

Comment: @TobySpeight Absolutely. I also noted that care is needed when piping: `cat file | LC_COLLATE=C sort` rather than `LC_COLLATE=C cat file | sort`.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using `LC_ALL=C` over `LC_COLLATE=C`?

Answer (score 9):

Check your environment variable `LC_COLLATE`.  The easiest thing will be to use the command `locales`.  If you want, you can set it to a different value.  For example, you can do (assuming bash)

```
export LC_COLLATE="C"
```

and that should fix your issue.

Comment: [yes it does](https://gist.github.com/artm/3a7c2e4e2d02d8810b96)

Comment: No,only LC_COLLATE no,but LC_ALL works fine

Comment: add `-l` flag to xargs

Comment: Solution found...find .  |grep -v scripts|xargs ls -lhd works without sort,the problem was utf8!

Comment: Another problem with that pipeline is that the result of `sort` is ignored because `ls` sorts its output by default. To actually have it display results in the order that `sort` produces `ls` could be given `-U` flag.

Comment: @elbarna Could you write an answer yourself, explaining what/how it worked? The comments here will not stay forever, and it would be good to have the real answer here.