# Order in which files within /etc/profile.d are sourced in CentOS 7.9? (for defining aliases)

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, alias

I have a question related to aliases/environment variables on CentOS 7.9. I am trying to make an alias for ll with:

```
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/Z-alias-ll.sh
```

However, after I do this and restart the console (I am using a fresh DigitalOcean CentOS 7.9 droplet and their droplet console), when I do "type ll", it says:

```
ll is aliased to `ls -l --color=auto'
```

When I search for the string "alias ll" within the folder with grep:

```
grep -rnw /etc/profile.d -e 'alias ll'
```

It gives me two other files, colorls.sh and colorls.csh:

```
/etc/profile.d/Z-alias-ll.sh:1:alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"
/etc/profile.d/colorls.csh:13:alias ll 'ls -l'
/etc/profile.d/colorls.csh:66:alias ll 'ls -l --color=auto'
/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh:9:  alias ll='ls -l' 2>/dev/null
/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh:55:alias ll='ls -l --color=auto' 2>/dev/null
```

If I move or delete these files, then my alias works. So I guess these files are overwriting my alias. But I thought since I prefixed the filename with Z-, that the latter would overwrite the former, as I figured it would be sourced later, Z* after c*, as that's how it works in Ubuntu.

I thought maybe I was doing it backwards, so I also did:

```
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/0-alias-ll.sh
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/-alias-ll.sh
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/alias-ll.sh
```

But then when I restart the console, "type ll" still says "ll is aliased to `ls -l --color=auto'".

To test which filename would end up being sourced last, I did:

```
echo 'alias testalias="ls -a"' > /etc/profile.d/0-alias-testalias.sh
echo 'alias testalias="ls -lh"' > /etc/profile.d/alias-testalias.sh
echo 'alias testalias="ls -F"' > /etc/profile.d/Z-alias-testalias.sh
```

After restart, "type testalias" then says, "testalias is aliased to `ls -lh'". So it was the file alias-testalias.sh that was sourced last. But, I don't understand why this is, since alphabetically it comes in between the other two.

My /root/.bashrc contains:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

I'm not sure, but I think it's this section of /etc/bashrc that is sourcing the /etc/profile.d files:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
# Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
# and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvars
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "$PS1" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

I created a file sort.sh with:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
     echo $i
done
```

Then did "bash sort.sh", that gave me:

```
/etc/profile.d/0-alias-ll.sh
/etc/profile.d/0-alias-testalias.sh
/etc/profile.d/256term.sh
/etc/profile.d/-alias-ll.sh
/etc/profile.d/alias-ll.sh
/etc/profile.d/alias-testalias.sh
/etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh
/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
/etc/profile.d/lang.sh
/etc/profile.d/less.sh
/etc/profile.d/which2.sh
/etc/profile.d/Z-alias-ll.sh
/etc/profile.d/Z-alias-testalias.sh
```

colorls.sh is in between the other files where I am trying to define alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto".

How does the sourcing order work here? Why is the filename "colorls.sh" being sourced after 0-alias-ll.sh, -alias-ll.sh, alias-ll.sh, and Z-alias-ll.sh? Even though alphabetically it's in the middle, and my sort.sh file also sorted it in the middle.

Is it maybe the "if" conditions in /etc/bashrc? I'm not sure what those conditions do exactly, or if it's something else and not the if conditions.

Comment: sort order depends on locale settings. Here is a useful link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335741/sort-with-case-sensitivity-lowercase-before-uppercase-in-macos-in-the-terminal and this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162084/sort-and-ls-why-arent-capitalized-letters-sorted-first and thi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413646/making-the-ls-command-sort-a-before-b-vs-a-b-a-b

Comment: Thank you very much. My locale is "LANG=en_US.UTF-8".  I was able to override colorls.sh by naming my file "z-alias-ll.sh", with a lowercase z. I guess my issue was that the uppercase Z was being sorted alphabetically before the lowercase "c" because of case sensitive sort.

Comment: What confuses me is if I put all these filenames in a file, and do "sort filenames.txt", it sorts in case-insensitive fashion. Where "a" comes before "c", and both "z" and "Z" come after "c". Yet it seems that the sourcing of files in /etc/profile.d is in case sensitive fashion, where "Z" comes before "c". I think that's what's going on, but I don't know why this is.